# Distribute multiple payments to invoice lines

Tags: sql-server, cursor, common-table-expression, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I'm having a problem allocating payments to invoice lines.

Data looks like this:

**Invoice lines table (sales):**

```
lineId   invoiceId   value
 1          1         100
 2          1         -50
 3          1          40
 4          2         500
```

**Payments table (payments):**

```
paymentId   invoiceId   amount
     1          1          50
     2          1          40
     3          2          300
```

Now, I want to know for each invoice line the payment details. The payments shall be allocated first to the smallest values (i.e. line 2, -50)

**The output should look like this:**

```
  lineId   invoiceId   value   paymentId   valuePaid   valueUnpaid
    2           1        -50        1          -50        0
    3           1        40         1          40         0
    1           1        100        1          60         40
    1           1        100        2          40         0
    4           2        500        3          300        200
```

The problem is solved in the post below, but the solution does not work if you have negative invoice values or if you have to split an invoice line in two payments.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58474/how-can-i-use-running-total-aggregates-in-a-query-to-output-financial-accumulati/219925?noredirect=1#comment431486_219925

This is what I've done so far based on the article above:

```
drop table dbo.#sales
drop table dbo.#payments 
            CREATE TABLE dbo.#sales
            (   lineId       int primary key,           -- unique line id
                invoiceId         int not null ,  -- InvoiceId foreign key
                itemValue      money not null  )       -- value of invoice line.


            CREATE TABLE dbo.#payments 
            (   paymentId       int primary key,        -- Unique payment id
                InvoiceId       int not null,           -- InvoiceId foreign key
                PayAmount          money not null
            )

            -- Example invoice, id #1, with 3 lines, total ammount = 90; id #2, with one line, value 500 

            INSERT dbo.#sales VALUES 
                (1, 1, 100),
                (2, 1, -50), 
                (3, 1, 40),
                (4, 2, 500) ;

            -- Two payments paid towards invoice id#1, 50+40 = 90
            -- One payment paid towards invoice id#2, 300


            INSERT dbo.#Payments
            VALUES  (1, 1, 50),
                    (2, 1, 40),

                    (3, 2, 300);

            -- Expected output should be as follows, for reporting purposes.
            /* lineId, invoiceId, value, paymentId, valuePaid, valueUnpaid
            2, 1, -50, 1, -50, 0
            3, 1, 40, 1, 40, 0
            1, 1, 100, 1, 60, 40
            1, 1, 100, 2, 40, 0
            4, 2, 500, 3, 300, 200 */


            WITH inv AS
              ( SELECT lineId, invoiceId, 
                    itemValue, 
                    SumItemValue = SUM(itemValue) OVER 
                    (PARTITION BY InvoiceId 
                     ORDER BY ItemValue Asc
                     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                              AND CURRENT ROW)
                FROM dbo.#Sales 
                )
            ,  pay AS
              ( SELECT 
                  PaymentId, InvoiceId, PayAmount as PayAmt,
                  SumPayAmt = SUM(PayAmount) OVER 
                    (PARTITION BY InvoiceId 
                     ORDER BY PaymentId
                     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                              AND CURRENT ROW)
                FROM dbo.#payments 
              )



                SELECT 
                inv.lineId,
                inv.InvoiceId,
                inv.itemValue,
                pay.PaymentId,
                PaymentAllocated = 
                  CASE WHEN SumPayAmt <= SumItemValue - itemValue
                         OR SumItemValue <= SumPayAmt - PayAmt
                  THEN 0
                  ELSE
                      CASE WHEN SumPayAmt <= SumItemValue THEN SumPayAmt      
                           ELSE SumItemValue END                             
                    - CASE WHEN SumPayAmt-PayAmt <= SumItemValue-itemValue        
                           THEN SumItemValue-itemValue                          
                           ELSE SumPayAmt-PayAmt END
                  END
            FROM inv JOIN pay
              ON inv.InvoiceId = pay.InvoiceId
            ORDER BY 
                inv.InvoiceId,
                pay.PaymentId;
```

The current output is:

```
lineId    InvoiceId    itemValue    PaymentId    PaymentAllocated    
  2           1        -50.00         1              0.00
  3           1        40.00          1              0.00
  1           1        100.00         1              50.00
  2           1        -50.00         2              0.00
  3           1        40.00          2              0.00
  1           1        100.00         2              40.00
  4           2        500.00         3              300.00
```

Any direction will be appreciated. Thank you.

More info on the allocation rules:

- Allocating first payment to the smallest sale (i.e. -50) was just a
  convention to insure all sales lines get payments. If I’d allocate
  arbitrary or with another rule, and line 1 (value 100) would get the
  first payment, I’d use all the payment for this line and the rest of
  the invoice would remain unallocated.
- As I said, it’s just an convention. If someone else comes with a
  different rule that works, it’s ok. Actually, the structure is
  simplified compared with the production tables: payments also have a
  payment date, type, … and a correct distribution should tell us what
  invoice lines were paid at each payment time.
- Payments are restricted by the logic of the system to be smaller then
  the sum of the invoice lines. Well, it might be a case when payments
  are greater: the total invoice is negative (ie: -100). In this case
  we can insert in the payments table amounts in the range of -100: 0
  and Total Payments are restricted to -100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found quite a simple and natural sollution - to allocate payments based on the percentage of each payment in the total value of the invoice.

```
                    drop table dbo.#sales
        drop table dbo.#payments

        CREATE TABLE dbo.#sales
        (   lineId       int primary key,           -- unique line id
            invoiceId         int not null ,  -- InvoiceId foreign key
            itemValue      money not null  )       -- value of invoice line.


        CREATE TABLE dbo.#payments 
        (   paymentId       int primary key,        -- Unique payment id
            InvoiceId       int not null,           -- InvoiceId foreign key
            PayAmount          money not null
        )

        -- Example invoice, id #1, with 3 lines, total ammount = 90; id #2, with one line, value 500 

        INSERT dbo.#sales VALUES 
            (1, 1, 100),
            (2, 1, -50), 
            (3, 1, 40),
            (4, 2, 500) ;

        -- Two payments paid towards invoice id#1, 50+40 = 90
        -- One payment paid towards invoice id#2, 300

        INSERT dbo.#Payments
        VALUES  (1, 1, 50),
                (2, 1, 40),
                (3, 2, 300);

        SELECT 
            s.lineId,
            s.InvoiceId,
            s.itemValue,
            p.PayAmount,
            p.PaymentId,
            round(p.PayAmount / ts.SumItemValue,3) as PaymentPercent,
            s.ItemValue  * round(p.PayAmount  / ts.SumItemValue,3) as AllocatedPayment
        FROM dbo.#sales s 
        LEFT JOIN dbo.#payments p 
          ON s.InvoiceId = p.InvoiceId
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT invoiceId, sum(itemValue) as SumItemValue FROM dbo.#sales GROUP BY invoiceId) ts 
            ON s.invoiceId = ts.invoiceId
        ORDER BY 
            s.InvoiceId,
            p.PaymentId;
```

And the resunt looks like this:

```
lineId  InvoiceId   itemValue   PayAmount   PaymentId   PaymentPercent  AllocatedPayment
1   1   100.00  50.00   1   0.556   55.60
2   1   -50.00  50.00   1   0.556   -27.80
3   1   40.00   50.00   1   0.556   22.24
3   1   40.00   40.00   2   0.444   17.76
2   1   -50.00  40.00   2   0.444   -22.20
1   1   100.00  40.00   2   0.444   44.40
4   2   500.00  300.00  3   0.60    300.00
```